# Closure under tautological implication?

Tags: logic

Suppose $\Gamma$ is a consistent and complete set of formulas of sentential logic (built up from sentence letters using the sentential connectives). Suppose we define a new set $\Gamma^*$ to be the complement of $\Gamma$. (1) Is $\Gamma$ complete? (2) Is $\Gamma$ consistent? (3) Is it closed under tautological implication?

Comment: Negating the steps in a proof does not produce a valid proof: from $A$ and $A \to B$, we derive $B$. But from $\lnot A$ and $\lnot (A \to B)$ i.e. $A \land \lnot B$ we cannot derive $\lnot B$.

Comment: I assume that the questions (1), (2) and (3) are relative to $\Gamma^*$.

Comment: The question is starting by specifying this is sentential logic, but then goes on the use the tags for FOL and model theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila just changed the tags--thank you

Comment: @Raton - Are you sure your question about in propositional logic and not about first-order logic? I don't see the interest of the question in the case of propositional logic, since classical propositional logic is [Post-complete](https://www.uni-log.org/contest2013/skura1.pdf), so every complete (in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_theory) sense, not in the sense of Post-complete) set of formulas in propositional logic is inconsistent, as correctly remarked by Asaf Karagila. On the contrary, the question is interesting in first-order logic, which is not Post-complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact $\Gamma$ is a complete and consistent set of sentences does not imply that its complement $\Gamma^*$ is consistent or complete.

1. Let $\Gamma$ be any complete and consistent set of sentences (e.g. the set axioms of [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic)) plus any universally valid sentence $A$ (e.g. the sentence $0=0$). Clearly, $\Gamma$ is complete and consistent. However, $\Gamma^*$ is not consistent because $\lnot A \in \Gamma^*$ by definition of complement, so $\Gamma^* \vdash \lnot A$, but also $\Gamma^* \vdash A$ by definition of validity. The error in your attempt of proof is that the fact that $\varphi \notin \Gamma^*$ does not imply that $\Gamma^* \not\vdash \varphi$.
2. Let $L$ be the language consisting of only an unary predicate symbol $P$ and a constant symbol $c$ (no identity). Let $\Gamma = \{\forall x P(x)\}$ (in $L$). Clearly, $\Gamma$ is complete and consistent, but its complement $\Gamma^* = \{\exists x \lnot P(x)\}$ is not complete because $\Gamma^* \not\vdash P(c)$ (take a model of $\Gamma^*$ with just one element) and $\Gamma^* \not\vdash \lnot P(c)$ (take a model of $\Gamma^*$ with two elements, the one that is the interpretation of $c$ has the property $P$ and the other one does not). The error in your attempt of proof is explained in Mauro Allegranza's comment.

Comment: Since the question specifies sentenial logic, I'd imagine that the answer is that $\Gamma^*$ is *never* consistent, since $p\lor\lnot p$ is always an element of $\Gamma$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - I know but the OP is a bit ambiguous in this respect, as you noticed in another comment.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - Moreover, in the OP $\Gamma$ is just a set of formulas and nowhere is written that it is closed by provability (i.e. $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ does not imply $\varphi \in \Gamma$). So, we don't know if $p \lor \lnot p \in \Gamma$, but for sure $\Gamma \vdash p \lor \lnot p$. When I say "$\Gamma$ is complete" I mean (in accordance with the OP, I guess) that for every formula $\varphi$, either $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ or $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \varphi$

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco, true--we are not given soundness of $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma$ is not necessarily maximal, but as you said, every inconsistent formula must be in $\Gamma^*$. And yes, I agree with your notion of completeness combined with consistency. We do not have both $\varphi \in \Gamma$ and $\neg \varphi \in \Gamma$, so we cannot have a proof of both from $\Gamma$.